# Using the keywords: CONTAINS, BEGINSWITH, ENDSWITH on multi-level keypaths in Realm.io

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am using, the 0.86.3 version of the realm.io framework.

Here is what my object looks like:

```
RLMArray <0x7fd1f3642a50> (
[0] Product {
    identifier = 4;
    overview = test;
    desc = test;
    reference = AB-123;
    category = Category {
        identifier = 2;
        name = Telescopic Arm;
        level = 1-1;
        parent = Category {
            identifier = 1;
            name = Arm;
            level = 1;
            parent = (null);
        };
    };
}
)
```

Everything looks fine so far, but when I'm trying to request:

```
RLMArray *products = [GEProduct objectsWhere:@"category.name contains 'telescopic'"];
```

I am getting an:

```
uncaught exception 'Invalid type', reason: 'Predicate 'CONTAINS' is not supported'
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that exception because multi-level keypath queries like CONTAINS, BEGINSWITH, ENDSWITH as well as case-insensitive queries on multi-level keypaths aren't supported. We're working on this feature, but don't have it for now.

These keywords **are** supported with direct property queries though, so you could re-work your query to look like this:

```
RLMArray *categories = [GECategory objectsWhere:@"name contains 'telescopic'"];
RLMArray *products = [GEProduct objectsWhere:@"category IN %@", categories];
```

I know it's not elegant, but until we have support for more complex multi-level keypath queries, that should work.

UPDATE (10-27-2014)

As of Realm v0.88.0, multi-level keypath queries like case-insensitive, CONTAINS, BEGINSWITH, ENDSWITH are supported so the poster's original attempt now works:

```
[GEProduct objectsWhere:@"category.name contains 'telescopic'"];
```

Realm v0.88.0 will be released shortly.

Comment: Why can't we just use the categories object (RLMArray) for the product request since RLMArray implements the NSFastEnumeration protocol ?

Comment: YES! I just edited my answer to reflect this. Thomas from Realm recently added support for this.

Comment: Oh Okay, thank you for the confirmation. It simplifies the process a bit then.